# How do you mass add an existing SMS list to Amazon SNS?

Tags: amazon-sns

We have been using the email => SMS gateway for our SMS messages in the past. We are now looking for a better way of doing this. In looking at AWS SNS, we can send SMS messages, but the customer has to be confirmed as a subscriber. We already have a list and want to skip that step if possible. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to skip the confirmation step for SMS subscriptions.